# Decorate a WCF service with Autofac

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac, decorator

I want to decorate WCF service with the following setup:

**SVC definition**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="Foo.IBarService, Foo"
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"%>
```

**Autofac registration**

```
builder.RegisterType<FooService>().Named<IFooService>("fooservice");

builder.RegisterType<LogFooService>().Named<IFooService>("logfooservice");

builder
    .RegisterDecorator<IFooService>(
        (context, inner) => context.ResolveNamed<IFooService>("logfooservice", TypedParameter.From(inner)),
        fromKey: "fooservice")
    .As<IFooService>();
```

This approach does work when the decorator is not the service itself. So for example an concrete service with a decorated IWhatever in the constructor. What is different with the svc service?

Comment: Not a lot to go on here. It would helpful to see error output, service contract & such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/wcf.html#using-decorators-with-services) state:

> The standard Autofac service hosting works well for almost every case, but if you are using decorators on your WCF service implementation then you need to use the multitenant WCF service hosting mechanism rather than the standard Autofac service host.